# CSS - responsive desidgn - media screen

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a css code like this:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* long code  just an example of top */
     .show_hide_top a.showLink {        /* small red link */
     left: 39% !important;
     padding-left: 8px;
     top: 15% ;
     }


@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width:1500px) { 
     /* long code for these devices ex: */
 .show_hide_top a.showLink {      
    left: 39% !important;
    padding-left: 8px;
    top: 18% ;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width:1299px) {     
      code for these devices
}

@media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
      code for these devices
}
```

However, my computer (1600) picks up the media code for the 1300-1500. 
Something (probably silly) is wrong.

Thank you so much for your opinion.

Comment: `1600` refers to the viewport size or your screen size? Could you fill an example fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: screen size. (disclaimer - I am new to programming, and I am not sure the differente.  I am using http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/ Thank you for asking.

Comment: well, those mediaqueries are checking the browser viewport, not the screen size. You should try use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` instead if that is the purpose

Comment: That made the trick! I even had tried that and commented it out, but I didn't use for all levels. Now I wrote in every single level and it works. Thanks! Please put it as an answer. Would you mind explaining the difference between viewsize and screen size? No big deal, I can find that out . Thanks a lot!

Comment: read MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to use min-device-width over min-width, since most desktop users do not have their browser maximized.

Comment: Well, it works on Chrome, Explorer, but doesn't make a dent on Firefox. I cleared the cache.

Comment: Worth reading:  http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/, http://designshack.net/articles/css/responsive-design-why-youre-doing-it-wrong/, http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/

Comment: @cimmanon these are good article. thank you. Read them quickly now but worth coming back and read them carefully, especially 1st and 3rd.

Comment: Perhaps this is just because you copied only parts of your CSS into your post, but you're not closing the first media query. Weird things are bound to happen because of this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I was using media query, firefox was not recognizing a generic id like #upper.

Example:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id='left"> content here </div>
   <div id="center">
      <div id="upper"> content here </div>
      ...
   </div>
   <div id="right">content here </div>
</div>
```

As soon as target #center #upper in the CSS, the media query worked ONLY for the target media and not as a generic rule.

Only #upper? Nope... It was reading and applying the media query for all devices, overwriting the generic CSS.

At first, toggling between min-devide-width and min-width seemed to work, but the problem persisted. So this is the permanent fix.

Make sure to use both full path in the generic CSS and in the media query.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries like this don't target *devices*, they target the width of the *browser viewport* in pixels. `@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) and (max-width:1500px)` was being picked up because your browser's viewport was in between 1300 pixels wide and 1500 pixels wide.

To demonstrate this idea better, try resizing your browser window and watch the different media queries being applied and removed.

Comment: Actually, its the viewport that is measured, not the the browser window.  The window would include chrome (if it exists), tool bars, scroll bar (this varies between browsers: some count it, some don't), etc.  The viewport the portion of the browser where the document you're viewing resides.  The viewport is almost *always* smaller than the display's resolution (especially if the browser window is not maximized).

Comment: But when I changed the code, it changed the look of the site. The problem now is that firefox is not responding to it. Only Chrome and IE.

Comment: @user2060451 seems like a different question, regardless we need to see the actual styles and which specifically aren't being applied to Firefox to look into the issue.

Comment: @DanielImms I posted the exact problem in the question. It's kind the same problem. Firebug reads the one for 1300-1500 media scren (line XXXX). IE and Chrome console reads line (YYYY). I mean reads and displays as such. I've been going back and forward with the two syntax (device and just min-width). Maybe i have been testing in different browsers, need to be more consistent. Than fix as necessary.